# Just dual booted my computer with ubuntu 20.04 and bluetooth manager is not opening up

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I am a complete noob when it comes to ubuntu/linux. For some reason my bluetooth manager is not opening and i can not turn on bluetooth from the setting app. I have uninstalled and installed the bluetooth already and have followed a long with previous trouble shooting stackoverflow posts regarding a similar problem with no luck. Anyone know any common methods that can fix this? thanks